# Foundation 5 top-bar height

Tags: responsive-design, zurb-foundation, navigationbar

Just wanted to find out, to change the height of Foundation 5's Top Bar Navigation, what is the correct way to do it without it breaking on mobile?

Adding any sort of padding or height works only for desktop but on mobile views it breaks the navigation.

Thanks for the help.
Nick

Answer (score 2):

The safest way will be using Sass version and modifying the line with `// $topbar-height: rem-calc(45);` in [`_settings.scss`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_settings.scss#L1389) (don't forget to uncomment it)

Answer (score 0):

Just add some lines of styles in your app.css

```
.top-bar, .title-area{height:46px; line-height:46px}
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button){padding:16px 22px;
.top-bar-section .has-dropdown > a{padding-right:22px!important;}
```

And you are done.